# 404 Error on using Spring AOP Logging

Tags: spring, logging, http-status-code-404, aop

I was trying to add AOP logger to the existing Spring(v3.1.3) application. Below is the code for the same. 
Application launches successfully and am able to login. But, once the flow reaches the Controller that's specified in the ApplicationLogger.java, am getting 404 error in the screen and unfortunately aint getting any error trace in the console. Not getting any clue.

Kindly help me out to find where i have gone wrong.

TIA,
Arun

### SERVLET.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache  http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd" >

    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Enables the caching through annotations -->
    <cache:annotation-driven />

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <bean id="appLogger"
         class="com.pmc.crm.risk.util.ApplicationLogger" />
    .
    .
    .
```

### ApplicationLogger.java

```
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;


@Aspect
public class ApplicationLogger
{
   /**
    * Log method entry.
    * 
    * @param joinPoint
    */

    @Before("execution(* com.pmc.crm.risk.mvc.controller.SearchController.loadParamSearch(..))")
   public void logEntry(final JoinPoint joinPoint)
   {
       System.out.println("*--*-*-*-* LOG ENTRY -*-*-*");
      log("Entering method " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + "...");
   }

   /**
    * Log method exit.
    * 
    * @param joinPoint
    */

   @After("execution(* com.pmc.crm.risk.mvc.controller.SearchController.loadParamSearch(..))")
   public void logExit(final JoinPoint joinPoint)
   {
       System.out.println("*--*-*-*-* LOG EXIT -*-*-*");
      log("Exiting method " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + ".");
   }
```

### SEARCHCONTROLLER.java

```
package com.pmc.crm.risk.mvc.controller;
import ....

@Controller
public class SearchController extends AbstractPolicyController{

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SearchController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/loadParamSearch.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView loadParamSearch(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,ModelMap model) throws Exception{

        try
        {
              System.out.println("...");
         }
         .
         .
```

Comment: Hi, 
I solved the issue. Here it is for anyone landing here in future on same issue: 
AbstractPolicyController was actually implementing an interface and servlet couldnt inject a proxy for the same (Investigating on the reason.) On removing the 'implements interfaceName' it worked good. Anyone who know the reason may pls let me know.

Comment: You should post this comment as an answer

Answer (score 0):

AbstractPolicyController was actually implementing an interface and servlet couldnt inject a proxy for the same (Investigating on the reason.) On removing the 'implements interfaceName' it worked good. Anyone who know the reason may pls let me know.